# How to use search with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I using python 2.7.11 and djnago 1.10.2. I created product models and saved 1000 products in my database.(postgrelsql) Actually, I used Django elasticsearch but its not working. its search only base on product name, i required if search category, colour, etc. Then show releated product. I tryed example.

```
from haystack import indexes
from product.models import Product

class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    product_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_name')
    product_colour = indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_colour')

    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

I created ProductColour models and used product_colour foreignkey in product moedls. If i search product_colour then display all releated data.

**Following some steps :-**

- Install django-haystack.
- Added haystack in **INSTALLED_APPS** settings.py file.
- Modify settings.py file.

  ```
  HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
      },
  }
  ```
- Added url in urls.py.

  ```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'^/search/?$', MySearchView.as_view(), name='search_view'),
  )
  ```
- product model.

  ```
  class Product(models.Model):
      product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      product_description = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
      product_colour = models.ManyToManyField(ProductColour, blank=True, default=None)
      .......
      .......
      .......
  ```
- search.html.

  ```
  <form method="get" action=".">
      <table>
          {{ form.as_table }}
          <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                  <input type="submit" value="Search">
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
  ```

Comment: Please post your search index template and the relevant parts of your Product model too.

Comment: @trixn plz check it sir, new updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used Django elasticsearch but its not working.

Acording to your haystack settings you are not using Elasticsearch. You are using the `SimpleEngine` which is no real search engine at all. To use Elasticsearch your settings must contain this instead:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

Note that haystack is not the search engine itself. It is just a tool to use several search engines from inside your django application. Have you already [installed elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch#installation)?

At the moment it doesn't work i guess, because the `SimpleEngine` can not handle your `Many2ManyField` correctly.

In your `ProductIndex` you defined the product_colour as a CharField. But you referenced the whole related model instance from your `ProductColour` model. Use a `MultiValueField` to do this:

```
from haystack import indexes
from product.models import Product

class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    product_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='product_name')

    # use a MultiValueField for your m2m relation
    product_colours = indexes.MultiValueField()

    # define this method that returns all the values for your product_colours index field
    # it must be called "prepare_{your field name}"
    def prepare_product_colours(self, object):
        return [colour.name for color in object.product_colour.all()]
```

Then you will need a template for your search index where the content of the `text` field will be generated [as described in the haystack documentation](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0/tutorial.html#handling-data).